# Removing an unusual freewheel

Tags: freewheel, tools

Could someone tell me which tool I can use to remove the freewheel in the attached picture please. I do have a couple of freewheel tools but they don't fit this particular freewheel.

Thanks

Chris

[image: Freewheel]

Comment: Well, first you remove the axle, or at least that lock nut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought an FR3 and it removed the freewheel in a few seconds. Thanks very much for your help :)

Chris

Comment: If you consider this to be the "final" answer, click the checkmark next to it to mark the question answered.

Answer (score 8):

The Park Tool FR-3 should fit that.

https://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-fr-3

[image]

Comment: OP might find that the FR-2 style works as well, but with only 2 lugs there's a little less engagement.  Also depends if this is a remove and dispose, or a remove and replace with a more-common freewheel fitting.

Comment: Thank you. Ideally it is  a remove and replace.